# Set theory and functions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give a one-to-one and onto function $f : [0,1] \to [0,1)$ without using 
Cantor–Bernstein theorem ?!

I can give $f(x) = x$ and so its one-to-one and onto but its problematic because $f(1)=1$ and so its not in $[0,1)$

Can any one give me hints or help , thanks

Comment: Without the full "Cantor-Bernstein theorem" can you still use the fact that the set of rational numbers is **countable**?  If you can, map every irrational x to itself. Order all of the rational numbers greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1, starting your order with 1, 0, ... and define $f(x_n)= f(x_{n+1})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow[0,1)$ this way:

- if $x\neq\frac1n$ for each natural $n$, $f(x)=x$;
- $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac1{n+1}$.